# How to get the text using beautiful soup python?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
<body> 
    <small> caption </small>
        text here 
    <small> caption </small>
        text here
</body>
```

I am using beautiful soup and I want to get just the text without the  tags. How can I do that? soup.find('body').text returns everything includes the  tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css selector and `next_sibling`

**Code**:

```
html='''<body> 
    <small> caption </small>
        text here 
    <small> caption </small>
        text here
</body>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for item in soup.select('body small'):
    print(item.next_sibling.strip())
```

Or you can use `contents`

```
html='''<body> 
    <small> caption </small>
        text here 
    <small> caption </small>
        text here
</body>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.find('body').contents[2].strip())
print(soup.find('body').contents[-1].strip())
```

Or you can split with new line and get the index value.

```
html='''<body> 
    <small> caption </small>
        text here 
    <small> caption </small>
        text here
</body>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.find('body').text.split('\n')[2].strip())
print(soup.find('body').text.split('\n')[-2].strip())
```